# Is 'compatriate' really an English word?

Tags: orthography, dictionaries, is-it-a-word, synonyms

I recently saw the word 'compatriate' used in a newspaper article. Upon looking it up, suspecting a typo (or even an eggcorn: it is easy to see how *compatriot* would be mixed-up with *expatriate* etc.), I was surprised to see [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compatriate) vouch for the word with the sole explanation: "Alternative spelling of compatriot".

However, not only did my googling yield extremely few credible uses of this spelling, none of the dictionaries I have access to have ever heard of it: both [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/compatriate) and [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/compatriate) do not return anything.

While I don't want to cast unfair aspersions on Wiktionary's reliability, I find it slightly suspicious that no other online sources mention this spelling...
And if it *is* an acceptable spelling, I would love to know what is its relation to the main spelling and whether it is tied to particular regional or historical practices.

Comment: I think this is a very good question, well written and thought out.

Comment: Wiktionary is extremely permissive with misspellings. They seem to be marked sometimes as misspellings and sometimes as "alternative spellings", without any discernible (to me) pattern.

Comment: Some words just ain't...words.

Comment: On the flip side, I once came across the word "expatriot" in a newspaper article. I thought to myself, "What's that? Someone who no longer loves his country?"

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: 'permissive' sounds like there is an authority granting indulgences. There is no natural pattern because of uncontrolled multiple authorship/lack of editorship. If you want to make up words there you can.

Comment: Good to know. Although I can't really see a good reason for including outright misspellings (given usage stats, we are way beyond prescriptivist/descriptivist debates here) with only a mention of "alternative spelling". By that reasoning, "its" should be labelled "alternative spelling" for "it's" and so on. Multiple authorship seems to work fine for Wikipedia, not sure why it fails Wiktionary.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The OED has no entry for *compatriate*. The entry for *compatriot* has no other spelling, and nor do any of the citations, from 1611 to 1871.

I shouldn't worry about casting aspersions on any source whose definitions are not backed either by implicit or explicit evidence.

Comment: This. "What can be asserted without evidence can be dismissed without evidence." — Christopher Hitchens

Comment: I know. Great innit?

Comment: What sources can Hitchens cite for that statement, @Robusto初夢?

Answer (score 3):

There are ~700 results for *?:compatriate* in [books](http://www.google.com/search?q=compatriate&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=compatriate&hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&ei=VrC6TtmHKIeg4gSk5oy2CA&start=20&sa=N&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=8ee6adb96009b707&biw=1363&bih=829); this is relatively rare, esp. compared to *compatriot* which is 3 orders of magnitude more common in the same corpus.

However, looking at books that also mention the word *dictionary* I found 'An etymological dictionary of the English language' by Walter William Skeat, unfortunately you can't see in what context it is mentioned there (or if it might have been a scanning error).

EDIT: COHA, COCA and BYU-BNC find no matches ([ref](https://www.english-corpora.org/)).

Answer (score 2):

It's amusing to note that *expatriot* (vs the proper *expatriate*) is in at least one [eggcorn database](http://eggcorns.lascribe.net/english/159/expatriot/), while *compatriate* (vs *compatriot*) is not. (Not yet, at least.)